# how do I create a splitter window with 2 CView windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-7, mfc

In a NON doc/view MFC application with office-like ribbon, with one CView, how do I create a splitter window with 2 CView windows, like Total Commander does it for file panes?
[image: Total Commander with 2 file panes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `CSplitterWnd` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5xttbe5t%28VS.80%29.aspx)) and then attach views oder other windows to it.